# Casting ObservableCollection<Object> to ObservableCollection<Type> Where type is unknown

Tags: c#

I'm looping through an object's (of type Object) properties, where i want to end up adding a IEnumerable or ObservableCollection to an already existing ObservableCollection property.

This is what i have so far:

```
var PropList = TempObject.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().ToList();
foreach (PropertyInfo ShowProp in PropList) 
{
   if (ShowProp.GetCustomAttribute<MarkedAttribute>() != null) 
   {
      Type TypeObject = ShowProp.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];

      // GetCollectionMethod returns a ObservableCollection<object>
      // The code below obviosuly doesn't work, but that is what i want to achieve.
      ObservableCollection<TypeObject> NewList = new ObservableCollection<TypeObject (GetCollectionMethod());

      TempObject.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(ShowProp.Name).SetValue(TempObject, NewList);
   }
}
```

As you can see I am stuck on casting an `ObservableCollection<object>` to `ObservableCollection<TypeObject>`

I have tried creating a new ObservableCollection using the Activator class, which worked fine. The code is below:

```
    // This creates an ObservableCollection<TypeObject>, but as soon as i fill it
    // with a IENumerable<Object> it get's converted into a ObservableCollection<Object>

    var listType = typeof(ObservableCollection<>);
    var concreteType = listType.MakeGenericType(TypeObject);
    var newList = Activator.CreateInstance(concreteType);
    newList = GetCollectionMethod();
```

In the example above, i made my `GetCollectionMethod()` return an `IENumerable<Object>` instead, but it only changes the original `<TypeObject>` of my ObservableCollection.

I am really frustrated with this and have googling for well over a half day, i would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: `TypeObject` is a variable, not a type. It can't be used as a generic parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the elements into your newly created collection, as such:

```
foreach(var elem in GetCollectionMethod())
    ((dynamic)newList).Add((dynamic)elem);
```

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
var newList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(concreteType);

foreach(var elem in GetCollectionMethod())
    newList.Add(elem);
```

Comment: And the winner is!
Thank you Chris, I will have to read up on the (dynamic) cast, it is exactly what i needed.

Comment: @Johnson11; Yes, `dynamic` can be quite fun. I also added the one without `dynamic` which might perform better, and is easier to follow.